# Improve Customtkinter performance in data extraction with Pandas

Tags: pandas, performance, data-manipulation, text-extraction, customtkinter

**Context**

I had to extract unorganized raw files into excel/word. Right now, I made a custom class to store the file as a Pandas data frame in one column and have multiple methods. The method will get the `self.__df` and store it in another variable. After getting the table using the first index and last index of the table, I used `.apply` to make the data cleanup.

**Problem**

It runs fine if I execute on the terminal, but when integrating with customtkinter, the GUI window hangs while extracting.
The app is frozen and not responding, so I used multithreading when the user clicked the button to execute the class method `.begin_extract()`. This solves the frozen, but somehow, the app is still hanging.

**Question**

-Is it possible to use multiprocessing to execute all extract methods in parallel so the app does not hang?

-In case it is not possible, is there another option to extract big files using customtkinter without it hanging?

I am considering switching the GUI framework from customtkinter into PyQt6 as I found that tkinter is single-threaded

Comment: Please supply a MRE of your issue https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.